# Page Control with different views on the page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to knw how to implement pagecontrol such that the each page contains different set of subViews.

for eg.

1. page 1 - UIImageView,UILabel
2. page 2 - UIButtons, UITextArea,etc.
3. page 3 - segmentedcontrols

please help me out guyz..m stucked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page` method create different view controller, for different page (parameter page represent index of page, int, starting from 0).

You have example [here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)

Comment: You mean that it not rotate? Do you have - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation methods returning YES, for all viewControllers?